# pixel_metrics - compute selected metrics only

Tags: r, lidr, point-cloud

Below is the code to compute all standard metrics from R package `lidR`.

```r
library(lidR)
x <- pixel_metrics(las_catalog, .stdmetrics, res = 30)
```

I want to compute only few pixel metrics only, like :

```
imean, zsd, iskew, zkurt, zpcum7, ipcumzq90, itot
```

Anybody got an idea on how to do this?

Comment: It is not possible. You must define your own function with your own metrics

Comment: @JRR Thank you for clarification. Isn't grid_metrics and pixel_metrics same thing?

Comment: pixel_metric is the new function name. If recent questions can refer to recent convention it's better.

Answer (score 1):

As JRR mentioned, define your own function. For example:

```
library(lidR)
f <- function(z, i) {
  list(
    mean = mean(z), 
    sd = sd(i),
    imean = mean(i))
}

m <- pixel_metrics(las, func = ~f(Z, Intensity))
```